# Have lost all the scene after loading a .unity in the same file

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie in Unity.

As it is said in the title, I have lost all my scene after I have loaded an imported asset (that has as extension .untiy) without knowing that it will replace the whole scene.

And even If I `ctrl` + `z` on it, it has not put me back to the old scene.

I have imported a tree from the asset store and then I went into that folder (from Unity), always by not knowing the effect that it will have, I opened the Scene folder of that asset and tried to put it in my scene so I did it too quickly that I missed to read what was written on the dialog window. Then all my scene was replaced by that one. I thought that I could restore it by doing `ctrl` + `z` but it is not doing that at all.

For now I have left the Unity window opened on purpose in case I could still get it back.

Hope someone could help me because I don't want to spend much time to restart it from zero.

Comment: Seems like you are doomed imo, one thing you could try: Go to you folder in windows explorer, right click see if you have an option in the menu that is somthing like, revert copy or revert last delete or somthing like this(i have HU windows so i dunno the english phrase for it)

Comment: Another way is that you might have a shadow copy if you are using windows

Comment: Did you save your Scene somewhere before? Of so find I in the Assets and just double-click it to open it in the scene view again

Comment: @Menyus What do you mean by a shadow copy ?

Comment: @derHugo No I didn"t save it somewhere else but I have saved my scene before replacing it by the tree scene. You mean I could try to go to the Scene Folder of the Assets folder  and then double-click on the one appears in the Scene folder ?

Comment: Thank you so much for both for your help. I Have tried to do what derHugo suggested and it worked in my case. So I have went to the folder Assets (that is located in the bottom left of the unity window), then to its Scene folder where I have found the old scene (that I have lost) named SampleScene.unity and then double-click on it and have recover all my old scene.

Comment: @YYY ooo you just opened another scene :D, i thought u have over written it :D, btw shadow copy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy

Comment: Btw if you want to import assets from one scene to another either create a Prefab or it is also possible to load multiple scenes parallel in the hierarchy and then simply move objects between them ;)

Comment: @Menyus Sorry for having misexplained my problem. Thank you for the link :)

Comment: @YYY it was totaly my mistake!

Comment: @Menyus No don't wory ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happened is that you only opened the new Scene in the Scene view. Most probably by double-clicking it instead of drag&drop it.

---

As long as you saved your original scene as an asset to the Assets folder that's easy to revert: Simply go to your original Scene in the Assets folder, double-click it and you should be fine ;)

---

Btw in order to import objects from one scene into another you can

- create a Prefab and drag it into your scene
- load both scenes into the Scene view next to each other by drag&drop. Then you can simply drag objects between both scenes.

---

In general you should use some version control (like. e.g. [Git](https://git-scm.com/))